# Select uncommitted data

Tags: mysql, transactions, pdo

I'm using transactions with PHP's PDO and MySQL and I'm wondering how to select, from within the transaction, some data that has not yet been committed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can glean from the documentation, the default transaction isolation level is REPEATABLE_READ, which should allow you to do what you want.

If your instance isn't defaulting to REPEATABLE_READ, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html for how to change it.